# How to store RSA private keypair to PKCS#12

Tags: java, rsa, pkcs#12

I have several RSA private keypairs which I now hold in a own format file.
I want to store them with Java into PKCS#12 keystore to have better access to them but cannot find clear example.

I already have the key in java.security.interfaces.RSAPrivateCrtKey.

Please help

Comment: Impossible to answer because of *... which I now hold in a own format file.*

Comment: Java allows to create and manage PKCS#12 files using the Java KeyStore system.

Comment: There are numerous examples of Java PKCS#12 keystore usage, what specifically is not clear?

Comment: I could not find any example for writing TO the keystore, only read FROM.

Answer (score -1):

Solution is (cert is selfsigned):

```
private static void createKeyStore(File file, String ksPassword, String keyPassword, String alias,
        Key privateKey, Certificate cert) throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {
    KeyStore ks = createEmptyKeyStore();
    ks.setKeyEntry(alias, privateKey, keyPassword.toCharArray(), new Certificate[] { cert });
    saveKeyStore(ks, file, ksPassword);
}
```